# sexy primes specific printing and tally

Tags: java

OK so the code I have is good, But instead of just displaying primes I need it to display the pairs that match and how many pairs there are, I know that this probably needs to go into the process sieve, I am summing I am going to need a tally system, and But I do not understand how to put them into pairs for printing out.

This is how they are supposed to printed out

Here are all of the sexy prime pairs in the range 1 to 42, one pair per line:

```
5 and 11 
7 and 13 
11 and 17 
13 and 19 
17 and 23 
23 and 29 
31 and 37
```

There were 7 sexy prime pairs displayed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class aleko_Sieve
{

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean primes [] = new boolean [50001];
int upperbnd;
int lowerbnd;

public aleko_Sieve ()
{

    primes[0] = false;
    primes[1] = false;

    for (int i = 2; i < primes.length; i++)
    {
        primes[i] = true;

    }

    getLower();
    getUpper();
    processSieve();
    showPrimes();
}

public void processSieve()
{

    for (int i =2; (i * i) <= upperbnd; i++)
    {

        for (int j = (i * i); j <= upperbnd; j = j + i)
        {

            primes[j] = false;
        }
    }
}

public void getLower()
{
    int x=0;
    do
    {
    System.out.println("Please enter a lower boundary ( 1 - 50000): ");
    lowerbnd = in.nextInt();
    if (( lowerbnd < 1) || (lowerbnd > 50000))
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid number");
        x = 1;
    }
    if (( lowerbnd > 1) || (lowerbnd < 50000))
    {
        x = 0;
    }
    }
    while ( x == 1);
}

public void getUpper()
{
    int x=0;
    do
    {
    System.out.println("Please enter a upper boundary ( 1 - 50000): ");
    upperbnd = in.nextInt();
    if (( upperbnd < 1) || (upperbnd > 50000))
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid number");
        x = 1;
    }
    if (( upperbnd > 1) || (upperbnd < 50000))
    {
        x = 0;
    }
    }
    while ( x == 1);
}

public void showPrimes()
{
    for (int i = 2; i < upperbnd; i++)
    {
        if (primes[i] == true)
        {
            System.out.println( i + " is prime");
        }
    }
}

public static void main (String args[])
{
    aleko_Sieve p = new aleko_Sieve();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you go to print a prime, see if the index 6 lower than the current one you just found is a prime and print them both.

```
//if found prime
if (i > 6)
{
    if (prime[i-7]==true)
    //print both primes
}
```

Comment: wouldn't the array size need to change depending on whether or not they enter 1-50000

Comment: Oh, you just said 42 so I assumed the number of sexy primes you were looking for was small. You can just search the primes array for the value of your current prime - 6. But that's a little harder and takes O(N) time. Also, I reread the code and edited my answer slightly.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over your array of primes as follows:

```
public void showSexy()
{
    int countPairs = 0;
    System.out.println("Here are all of the sexy prime pairs in the range 1 to 42, one pair per line:");
    for (int i = 2; i < upperbnd - 6; i++)
    {
        if (primes[i] == true && primes[i+6]== true)
        {
            countPairs++;
            System.out.println( i + " and " + (i+6));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("There were " + countPairs + " sexy prime pairs displayed");
}
```

Couple of things to note:

1. the loop has an upper bound of `upperbnd - 6` since otherwise you can't find another prime that is 6 greater
2. Create a `countPairs` variable that is incremented each time a pair is found
3. Print the pair when you find it (you already have the array with `true`/`false` so it's easy to find them)
4. Print the count of pairs after you have gone through the entire list

Comment: Hmm the piece of code you gave me is giving me errors on the System.out.println(i + " and " i+6);

Comment: Sorry - try `System.out.println( i + " and " + (i+6));`. Late here, and not wearing glasses...